# @ConditionalOnBean(ClientRegistrationService::class) fails to match JdbcClientDetailsService

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm writing a REST controller that exposes CRUD operations based on the type of OAuth2 services beans that are found, something like this:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnBean(ClientDetailsService::class)
fun clientServiceController(
  clientDetailsService: ClientDetailsService
): ClientDetailsServiceController {
  return ClientDetailsServiceController(clientDetailsService)
}

@Bean
@ConditionalOnBean(ClientRegistrationService::class)
fun clientRegistrationServiceController(
  clientRegistrationService: ClientRegistrationService
): ClientRegistrationServiceController {
  return ClientRegistrationServiceController(clientRegistrationService)
}
```

I want to only register a controller that exposes `ClientDetailsService` if we do not have a `ClientRegistrationService`. If it does exist, to additionally register a controller for the methods in that interface.

One of our modules that registers these controllers, also registers a `JdbcClientDetailsService` bean, which implements both interfaces. Yet, the `@ConditionalOnBean(ClientRegistrationService::class)` fails to match it, so only the first bean is created by not the second.

This is an example of how we declare the `JdbcClientDetailsService`:

```
@Bean
fun jdbcClientDetailsService(
  passwordEncoder: PasswordEncoder,
  dataSource: DataSource): JdbcClientDetailsService {

  return JdbcClientDetailsService(dataSource).apply { setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder) }
}
```

The odd thing is that `@Autowired ClientRegistrationService` does successfully inject `JdbcClientDetailsService`.

What am I missing? How can I declare a bean that implements both interfaces, and match correctly against the conditionals? Is there a work around?

Answer (score 0):

I succeed to get around this with the following:

```
@Bean
@Lazy
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public ClientRegistrationService registrationDetailsService(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer configurer)
        throws Exception {
    ClientDetailsService built = configurer.and().build();

    if (built instanceof ClientRegistrationService) {
        return (ClientRegistrationService) built;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException(built + " is not instanceof " + ClientRegistrationService.class);
    }
}
```

It applies the same pattern as ClientDetailsServiceConfiguration, and rely on the same configurer.

We might get ride of '@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)' if you want to retrieve an actual JdbcClientDetailsService